# How to fetch varchar type data from MySQL using flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am have a flask application which is interaction with MySQL db using `flask_sqlalchemy` package.
I am trying to fetch data `where slug = 'my_slug_data' and is_published=false and is_delete=false` using below query.but i am not getting any response back.

```
aPost = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=slug, is_published=True, is_delete=False)
print(aPost)
```

When i am printing **aPost**. then it is showing below query

```
SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.created_by AS posts_created_by, posts.created_on AS posts_created_on, posts.updated_on AS posts_updated_on, posts.is_published AS posts_is_published, posts.is_delete AS posts_is_delete, posts.title AS posts_title, posts.slug AS posts_slug, posts.sub_title AS posts_sub_title, posts.content AS posts_content, posts.tags AS posts_tags
FROM posts
WHERE posts.slug = %(slug_1)s AND posts.is_published = true AND posts.is_delete = false
```

Below is posts model

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    #id, created_by, created_on, updated_on, is_published, is_delete, title, slug, sub_title, content, tags

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    is_published = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    is_delete = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(130), nullable=True, unique=True)
    sub_title = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    tags = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)
```

**Can anyone guide me where i am doing wrong in the query?**

Comment: You should paste your `Posts` model

Comment: @WaketZheng updated

Comment: @hd1 do you mean, i need to rename slug to some other name ?

Comment: Apologies for the misleading comment, @SangramBadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for obj in Posts.query.all():
    print(obj.id, obj.slug, obj.is_published, obj.is_delete)
print(Posts.query.filter_by(slug=slug))
print(Posts.query.filter_by(slug=slug, is_published=True))
aPost = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=slug, is_published=True, is_delete=False).first()
print(aPost)
```

Comment: i am getting error `(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)'), <traceback object at 0x00000186967692C0>)`
for `print(Posts.query.all().count())`

Comment: Sorry, I use Django now, and does not write code about flask_sqlalchemy for a long time. But it is better to check whether there is data in db.

Comment: `print(Posts.query.all())` - i am getting output now. There are 2 records and i am getting

Comment: I got the answer need to use `aPost = Posts.query.filter_by(slug=slug, is_published=True, is_delete=False).first()`

Comment: As i got the clue from your answer, i will accept your answer. but if you modify your answer with `.first()`